# Image compression with Huffman tree

Tags: java, image, huffman-code

So I recently built a Huffman tree and it worked well for encoding text. Now I wanted to try and see if I could compress images aswell. Obviously, images that differ little (like abstract images) should be better to compress. My question is if I'm thinking about this correct. Let's say I got a jpg image that is 786x463 pixels big. Each pixel have 3 color values, which each can be 256 different colors, therefore 8 bits. We got three colors, RGB, so each pixel is effectivly 24 bits all and all. So (786x463) * 24 = 853 40 16 bits which is about 1 Mb.

Now I can loop over all the pixels, and put the three color values in a list, and then count the occurences of each color from that list and remove the duplicates and put them in my tree.

```
private void saveColors() {
    BufferedImage img = readImage(url);
    int width = img.getWidth();
    int height = img.getHeight();
    int size = (width * height) * 3;
    pixels = new ArrayList<Integer>(size);

    WritableRaster inraster = img.getRaster();
    for (int i = 0; i < width; i++)
        for (int j = 0; j < height; j++) {
            pixels.add(inraster.getSample(i, j, 0));
            pixels.add(inraster.getSample(i, j, 1));
            pixels.add(inraster.getSample(i, j, 2));
        }
    countColors();
}

/**
 * Counts occurences and removes duplicates
 */
private void countColors() {
    List<Integer> duplicateRemoved;
    duplicateRemoved = new ArrayList<Integer>(pixels);

    Set<Integer> hs = new HashSet<Integer>();
    hs.addAll(duplicateRemoved);
    duplicateRemoved.clear();
    duplicateRemoved.addAll(hs);

    pixelFreq = new int[duplicateRemoved.size()];
    pixelArr = new int[duplicateRemoved.size()];

    for (int i = 0; i < pixelArr.length; i++) {
        int p = duplicateRemoved.get(i);
        int count = Collections.frequency(pixels, p);
        pixelArr[i] = p;
        pixelFreq[i] = count;
    }
//Build tree...
}
```

So I tried to encode this picture : [Just black and white[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/juJIg.jpg)

And the encoding results gave me this:

```
color   Freq    Code   bits
'0' -- 4410 -- '0010'--17640
'1' -- 1185 -- '001001'--7110
'2' -- 858 -- '00100'--4290
'3' -- 591 -- '00100101'--4728
'4' -- 315 -- '0010010101'--3150
'5' -- 180 -- '0010010101010'--2340
'6' -- 75 -- '0010001010010'--975
'7' -- 30 -- '00100010100100'--420
'8' -- 9 -- '0010001010010000'--144
'246' -- 3 -- '001000101001000'--45
'247' -- 15 -- '001000101001000'--225
'248' -- 84 -- '0010001010'--840
'249' -- 138 -- '001001010101'--1656
'250' -- 273 -- '0010001010'--2730
'251' -- 480 -- '0010001'--3360
'252' -- 1227 -- '0001'--4908
'253' -- 1749 -- '00010'--8745
'254' -- 2475 -- '00'--4950
'255' -- 1077657 -- '0'--1077657
 Original compressed reduction percent
8734032--1145913---7588119--86.879906%
```

Which seems resonably, white occurs the most of times and get's the smallest code, where the black get's a slightly larger code.
Now as you can see, the total number of bits ended up being 1145913.
So we calculate the difference: 8534016 - 1145913 = 7388103 which is about 0,4 Mb. So the difference is about 0,6 Mb, 60% reduction.

So my question is, am I thinking about this right? I mean counting all the color values for each pixel?

Comment: What do you mean with "get this right?" There clearly are better compression (smaller image) algorithms available for images than what you're proposing, if that's what you mean. The jpeg that you posted is only 9306 bytes. If you're asking about Huffman encoding - you may get better compression if you consider multiple pixels in a run as a single element when you build the dictionary.

Comment: Yes I know there are better compression algorithms  for this, just wanted to try this one out. But what I'm wondering if my implementation of this is correct, to count all the color values for each pixel.

Comment: Again, what do you mean with "correct" ? If you can compress the image to a smaller size, and then uncompress it back to the original, then you're "correct". There is nobody looking over your shoulder here with an objective definition of "correct".